# How scientific notation inclusion is decided implicitly in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, scientific-notation

What are the criterias in python for scientific notation inclusion in a calculation result?

```
d1 = Decimal('500')
d2 = Decimal('0.25')
print d1/d2
```

This gives the result **2.0E+3**

If i include 2 zeroes after decimal point for 500, that is ,

```
d1 = Decimal('500.00')
d2 = Decimal('0.25')
print d1/d2
```

This gives the result **2000**

Also how can it be made sure that there are no scientific notation in the result?

Answer (score 1):

See [FAQ](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#decimal-faq) in the official docs:

> Q. Some decimal values always print with exponential notation. Is there a way to get a non-exponential representation?
>
> A. For some values, exponential notation is the only way to express the number of significant places in the coefficient. For example, expressing 5.0E+3 as 5000 keeps the value constant but cannot show the original’s two-place significance.
>
> If an application does not care about tracking significance, it is easy to remove the exponent and trailing zeroes, losing significance, but keeping the value unchanged:

```
def remove_exponent(d):
    return d.quantize(Decimal(1)) if d == d.to_integral() else d.normalize()
```

```
>>> remove_exponent(Decimal('5E+3'))
Decimal('5000')
```